# pg_prepare problem with string parameters

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I am having problem with getting results from prepared statements in postgres

My `pg_prepare` query is

`"SELECT username, firstname, lastname FROM myProject.myProject_users WHERE username = $1 AND password = $2"`

Obviously, username and password are strings (let's not talk about security, just query itself).
But when I do `pg_execute` for my query with let's say `array($username, $password)` where both variables of array are strings, I am getting zero lines as result.

I am suspicious it's because of query looking like

`"SELECT ... WHERE username = admin AND password = password"`

instead of

`"SELECT ... WHERE username = 'admin' AND password = 'password'"`

so it's without apostrophes.

I tried like everything from sending `array("'".$username."'", ...)` to building that query so it has apostrophes before and after `$1`, `$2`.

What's the catch?

Comment: Maybe that's because your conditions are not met? Execute query in pq cli or hardcode values and see the results.

Comment: cmon man I am not that stupid :D

Comment: You have to share your code if you want more than guessing. Don't be offended if people suggest that you made some trivial mistake, because that's what you obviously did.